# Tasks needing admin password (Finder, Installer) hang with beachball for minutes

Tags: macos, finder, password

Taks needing and admin password, like deleting certain files in the Finder or running an application installer, hang for minutes with a beachball. After a couple of minutes the dialog asking for an admin password appears finally.

Once the window finally appears it also takes a minute to be usable. After I entered the password everything works just fine.

The same also happens when trying to mount a disk image with a password. It takes minutes for the password window to show up.

I can't see anything happen in Activity Monitor. CPU usage is low and RAM is plentiful. Other applications continue to run quickly.

OS X 10.10.2

MacBookPro11,3 2.8 GHz i7 16 GB RAM

Comment: Did you try restoring the permissions, the System and the User?

Answer (score 2):

In order to eliminate the User profile problem, log in as different user and check.

I would also repair the System permissions (in disk Utility) and the User permissions (the ACLs)